# How to use component javascript in the Pentahoo Data Integration

Tags: javascript, pentaho, etl

Hello I am currently working with (PDI) Pentahoo Data Integration. My problem is the component to use javascript code. This was not well recognized values of type 'string', but values instead of type 'int' have no problems.
This is my code:

```
var q=1;
if(Id_Ccosto =='5189' || Desc_Ccosto=='Comedor CIME')
    q =2;
```

The value of (q) never changes because does not enter in the if().In other places where I use `if(id==15)` it works.
Sorry, StackOverflow not let me upload images.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your transformation? Include screenshots of the input fields of the javascript step and the javascript code itself if possible.

Comment: It's strange. Your javascript correctly processes the output of Data Grid step with two String columns in pdi-4.4.0. Are you sure there are no spaces or CR/LF characters in your data?